# The declared package "org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift" does not match the expected package "java.org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift"

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-hive

I import the spark source to eclipse:

[image]

But I got some error:

The declared package "org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift" does not match the expected package "java.org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift"

[image]

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want the "java" folder in there, the top level of the source folder should be "org", i.e. the top level package name.

Comment: But I want to know why spark sources developer declear the "java" folder in there?

Comment: This is about how you've imported this into Eclipse, there's nothing wrong with the layout of the source code per se. It looks like you have source code in the folders: src/main/java, src/test/java, and src/gen/java.

You have correctly got src/main/java and src/gen/java as source folders in Eclipse, but you've got src/gen as a source folder instead of src/gen/java.